# Barplot representing percentage of individual groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

Sample data is as follows

```
data = data.frame(group1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1),
                  group2 = c(3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3))
```

I want to create a barplot that has, groups 1, 2, 3 on the x axis, and the bars to represent the proportions within the group.

For example,

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = group2, fill = group1))+
geom_bar(position = "dodge")
```

Has the bars next to each other as I want, but only represents counts, whereas

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = group2, fill = group1))+
geom_bar(position = "fill")
```

gives the proportions but they are stacked - how do I combine the two to have the proportions, but displayed next to each other?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

We can get the percentage grouped by 'group2' and then plot

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
data %>% 
    group_by(group2) %>% 
    summarise(group1 = mean(group1)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = group2, y = group1)) +
        geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = 'identity') +
        ylab('percentage')
```

-output

[image]

---

Or another option if it is relative percentage

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = group2)) + 
         geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)))+
         ylab('percentage')
```

-output

[image]